# Preview video through Embed src?

Tags: php, video-player, video-thumbnails

I am working on a site where the admin inserts the embed code in the backend and the video is played on the frontend. I want to ask if it is possible to have preview(multiple images) for the video as the video is not in the database or on the server, we are just using the embed src for the video.
for example:

```
<iframe src="**abc.com/embed**" some parameters></iframe>
```

Now i copied the src and inserted into the database. I want to have the preview of the video? Is it possible..???
I hope i have cleared myself.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of asking whether `It is possible`, Why not you have a try and see it ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: i was trying to do this with ffmpeg, but hard luck.. I thought this might not be possible.. can we do it using ffmpeg??

Comment: You want to know whether it is possible by any other plugin .. If you are looking to do that only by ffmpeg then you shall refer this [link](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-generate-video-previews-with-ffmpeg/138)